# Detecting if user has in call status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar, in-call

How do I detect if user is in-call or tethering? I have a subview for iAd like this:

```
_UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
_UIiAD.delegate = self;

[_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,470,320,50)];
[self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];\
```

And it sets it wrong when the user is in call? How do I detect this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`UIApplicationDelegate` has these two methods.

```
// ObjC
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame;   // in screen coordinates
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame;

// Swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarFrame oldStatusBarFrame: CGRect)
```

And there are `Notifications` too.

```
//ObjC
UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification

// Swift
Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrame
Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame
```

but they're not posted on the launch of the app, so I wouldn't recommend it.

The simulator has an useful tool to test that.

> Hardware->Toggle In-Call Status Bar (⌘Y)

I would suggest you to implement those methods on your `AppDelegate` file. They will be called when the status bar change it's height. One of them it's called before and the other after the change.

Assuming you want that your `ViewController` to be notified when the change occurs, one option, is to send notifications. Like this

First, add this property/variable on `AppDelegate`

```
// ObjC
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect currentStatusBarFrame;

// Swift
var currentStatusBarFrame: CGRect = .zero
```

then, implement `willChangeStatusBarFrame`

```
// ObjC
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
{
    self.currentStatusBarFrame = newStatusBarFrame;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Status Bar Frame Change"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:@{@"current status bar frame": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newStatusBarFrame]}];

}

// Swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    currentStatusBarFrame = newStatusBarFrame
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Status Bar Frame Change"),
        object: self,
        userInfo: ["current status bar frame": newStatusBarFrame])
}
```

And we're done with the base of our `Status Bar Frame Checker`. The next part you implement on any `ViewController` that needs to know the status bar frame.

Any time you want to get the status bar frame, you do like so

```
// ObjC
[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] currentStatusBarFrame]

// Swift
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).currentStatusBarFrame
```

And to be notified when it changes, add this to `ViewDidLoad` method.

In ObjC

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(statusBarFrameChanged:)
                                             name:@"Status Bar Frame Change"
                                           object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
```

And implement this method

```
- (void) statusBarFrameChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGRect newFrame = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"current status bar frame"] CGRectValue];
    NSLog(@"new height %f", CGRectGetHeight(newFrame));
}
```

In Swift

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Status Bar Frame Change"),
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: nil) { (note) in
                                            guard let currentStatusBarFrame = note.userInfo?["current status bar frame"] as? CGRect else {return}
                                            print("New Height", currentStatusBarFrame.height)
    }
```

Comment: The right answer is not to do layout with hard-coded numbers in the first place and use auto layout, auto resize masks, or adjusting based on your current size in layoutSubviews rather than actually monitoring the status bar's state. (For example, the OP's code won't work on 3.5" displays for the same reason.)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this in landscape? In landscape, the status bar does not change height in a call, so the frame changed notifications are never called.

Comment: I think you'd want to change "Status Bar Frame Change" with UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification

Answer (score 1):

I beliveyou have status bar problem which make you view shift downward.  You can use below code to solve that

**In swift**

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing(rawValue: UIViewAutoresizing.RawValue(UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.rawValue) | UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleTopMargin.rawValue)))
```

It solved my issue caused by status bar when user is in call. for objective C reference [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367166/3322147)