# Detect Blue flashing status bar in ios programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

When google map is using location service and we go to background then one status bar with blue flashing background with information "Google map is using your location" is coming.

[image]

Now when I open my application (or any other application) you always see that blue flashing bar .

My question is can I detect that status bar is with blue flashing information is active now or not programmatically?

Comment: Have you try by calculating Screen Height of Window when application comes to foreground.. by using Notification.?

Comment: no @MS. getting the same origin and size for window frame.

Comment: yes but I check the subview that I adding in window and it is giving difference. thanks for suggesting to check frame size @MS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting if user has in call status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841418/detecting-if-user-has-in-call-status-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIApplicationDelegate has these 2 methods

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame;   // in screen coordinates
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame;
```

You can refer this link for more details.

[Detecting if user has in call / Any Activity status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841493/1323519)