# Managing UIWindow height when on call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, frame

I am working in `IOS` application where all the work is done programmatically and we haven't used `autolayout` in complete application.

But I am facing one issue here from long time that when I got call or if my hotspot is on in that case my device status bar height changes.

So In this case how I can manage the application `frame` so that my `UIView's` will be managed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to set the views and subviews autoresizing correctly through code(in your case).

OR 
Add this method to your **AppDelegate.m** :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame (CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame 
{
   // update layout
}
```

You can update the layout here with code.

Try this for autoresizing views:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Thank you @Arpit Dongre. I have tried with this method and also with the different notifications available from where I can get the status bar height. But I want to know is there any way I can manage UI once I will get the height.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil Did you try autoresizing? I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the height of the status bar changes the following functions will be called. Just add these functions to your `AppDelegate.m` file. They will be called when the status bar changes its height. One of them is called before and the other after the change.

```
//Called before the change
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
{
//Change the size of Window
self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
//In your case it will be
//self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height - 40);
} 

//Called after the change
//- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame{
//Change the size of Window
//}
```

## Starting :

[image]

## Changing statusBar Height by toggling in-Call Status Bar

[image]

## Final Result with Changed Frame:

[image]
Hope this helps. Happy Coding. 
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841493/5807290)